# C# Winform and ASP.Net and Xamarin

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms, xamarin

Right now, I'm in C# Winform and I would like to use my Windows Application with ASP.NET including with Xamarin. So, I need to know, what kind of program do people often use to make application run in all kind of devices (Computer + Web Browser + Smartphone)? And what should I use, WPF or UWP or which one?

Answer (score 1):

This question is a bit broad/unclear, but you could consider porting your app to an ASP.NET frontend, and then load it with a wrapper on mobile phones and desktops.

Essentially create native apps that in turn load the ASP.NET web app. This is a quite common approach as it reduces development time.

Comment: Hi.

I'm sorry for my English. What I need to know is, if I develop Winform, how can I show it into Web and Mobile with C#? Which one I should start first?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you clearly, you want to make an ASP.NET Core application.
That is an webapp and if you use bootstrap it will scale on every device.
And because you use Core, you can host the webapp on every server (windows, linux etc.)

Comment: Does ASP.NET Core application can be use with Winform? As I know, ASP.Net is for Webapp only. What I plan to do is, since I always use Winform, can I show what I make from Winform to Web and Mobile Apps?

Comment: @Thoiruddin no.